# How to model struct that contains reference to it's definition in python through ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

trying to wrap struct the reference it's definition as below

> foo.c

```
typedef struct Foo {
  struct Foo *foo;
} Foo;
```

how to model that, for example

> foo.py

```
class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('foo', pointer(Foo))]
```

of course python doesn't interpret that, I could use c_void_p instead of pointer(Foo), and cast it's value as follow

```
F = clib.get_foo()
cast(F.foo, pointer(Foo)) #although i'm not sure if it would work
```

but, is there a way to model that struct in a python class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Incomplete Types](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types):

> ... . In [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes), we can define the `cell` class and and set the `_fields_` attribute later, after the class statement.

Applying that to the current problem, the code would look *smth* like:

```py
import ctypes as ct


class Foo(ct.Structure):
    pass

Foo._fields_ = (
    ("foo_ptr", ct.POINTER(Foo)),
)
```